# Is there a gerundive of "faciō"?

Tags: morphology, passive-voice, gerundive

*Faciō*, "to make" or "to do", is a common Latin verb. It's famous for being suppletive: it's missing most of its passive forms, and instead uses the active forms of the separate verb *fiō* "to become". (Compare English "go", which lost its past tense and had to steal some forms from the separate verb "wend".)

If I wanted to say that something "must be made", using a gerundive of obligation, how would I do that? Is that one of the rare passive forms of *faciō* that does exist, and can be used normally? Or would I use a gerundive of *fiō* instead, even though it's morphologically a passive form?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is. A couple of notes:

- **Faciendus** (-a, -um) is attested. Perseus gives [21 results](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/searchresults?target=la&collections=Perseus:collection:Renaissance&phrase=&collections=Perseus:collection:PDILL&page=1&exclude_words=&search=Search&collections=Perseus:collection:Germanic&any_words=&collections=Perseus:collection:Arabic&collections=Perseus:collection:RichTimes&collections=Perseus:collection:cwar&collections=Perseus:collection:Greco-Roman&all_words=faciendus) of the former. These include several forms of faciendus + [esse] (est, erat, esset)
- There is also [a number of instances](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/searchresults?target=la&all_words=faciendi&phrase=&any_words=&exclude_words=&documents=) of gerund **faciendum, -i, -o**
- **Ad faciendum**:

  *Ad satis faciendum* ([Cic. Clu. 4](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0010:text=Clu.:chapter=4&highlight=faciendum)):

  > Etenim tibi si in praesentia non potuero, tamen multae mihi **ad satis faciendum** reliquo tempore facultates dabuntur

  *Ad male faciendum* ([Pl. Epid. 3.2](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0038:act=3:scene=2&highlight=faciendum).44):

  > Nimis dóctus ille est **ad male faciendum**.

Comment: You could also search for forms with *faciund-*. Combined, there are quite a few results, although, as you implied, quite a few will be gerunds rather than gerundives. https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23faciend+%7C+%23faciund